# Cohomology class $ H^k(X; \pi_{k-1}(Y,y_0))$ as obstruction

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes, obstruction-theory

I am following these notes http://scgp.stonybrook.edu/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/lecture-1.pdf
on obstruction theory.
Let $X$ be a CW complex and denote by $X^{(k)}$ its $k$-skeleton. Suppose
that $Y$ is a simply connected space with basepoint $y_0$ and suppose that
$f : X^{(k-1)} \to Y$ is a continuous map. Then the association to each oriented
$k$-cell $e^k \cong D^k$ of $X$ of the element in $\pi_{k-1}(Y,y_0)$
corresponding to the composition

$$   S^{k-1}  \xrightarrow{\eta_{e^k}}  X^{(k-1)} \xrightarrow{f}  Y  $$

where $\eta_{e^k}$ is the is the attaching map for $e^k$, defines a CW $k$-cochain on
$X$ with coefficients in $\pi_{k-1}(Y,y_0)$, called the obstruction cochain for extending $f$ to
the $k$-skeleton. It is denoted $\mathcal{O}(f)$.

Next, there is a **Lemma 1.2**:
$\mathcal{O}(f)$ is a cocycle. If $g : X^{(k-1)} \to Y $ has the property that
$f \vert _{X^{(k-2)}}  = g \vert _{X^{(k-2)}} $ then  $\mathcal{O}(f) -
\mathcal{O}(g)$ is a coboundary. Conversely, given any
coboundary, $dc$, there is a map $g : X^{(k-1)} \to Y$ agreeing with $f$  on
$ X^{(k-2)}$ such that $\mathcal{O}(f) -\mathcal{O}(g) = dc $.

After the proof in the notes is remarked (see page 2) that in view of this
lemma the cohomology class $ [ \mathcal{O}(f)] \in
H^k(X; \pi_{k-1}(Y,y_0))$ is the obstruction to extending
$ f \vert _{X^{(k-2)}} $ over $X^{(k)} $ in the sense that the cohomology class
$ [\mathcal{O}(f)] $ vanishes if and only if there is such
an extension.

I not understand how to read off from this lemma 1.12 that $ [\mathcal{O}(f)] $ gives an "obstruction class " for extension of $f$ to $k$-skeleton. Could somebody explain it? Unfortunately, this relation between the lemma and obstruction property of $ [\mathcal{O}(f)] $ the remark is refering to is not apparent to me from the script.

**#UPDATE#:** thanks to the discussion with Mariano below it follows that
the implication "$f$ extends to $X^{(k)} \to Y$ -> class $[O(f)]$
vanishes" has nothing to do with this *lemma 1.2*. It just follows immediately from
the fact that if $f : X^{(k-1)} \to Y$ extends to $X^{(k)} \to Y$,
then every composition
$S^{k-1}  \xrightarrow{\eta_{e^k}}  X^{(k-1)} \xrightarrow{f}  Y$
factors through $k$-ball $D^k$ which has the attatching sphere $S^{k-1}$ as boundary and therefore $O(f)$ is
zero homotopic.

So my question reduces to the converse implication, namely why
Lemma 1.2 implies or verbatimly "in view of this lemma" we get the implication that if the class $ [ \mathcal{O}(f)] \in
H^k(X; \pi_{k-1}(Y,y_0))$ is zero, then
$f : X^{(k-1)} \to Y$ extends to $X^{(k)}$.

Does maybe the lemma 1.2 in the text contain an error with respect to the right index shift of the $k$'s? Since otherwise I not see how to conclude from the lemma 1.2 that the class $[O(f)]$ is a "obstruction class" in sense the quotedremark on page 2.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: my quoting of lemma 1.2 contained some typos. Now it's identical to the script's version.

Comment: What you wrote is exactly the characterization of an obstruction class. The mentioned lemma from the script tells just that $f \vert _{X^{(k-2)}}$ extends to certain $g : X^{(k-1)} \to Y$ iff the difference $\mathcal{O}(f) -
\mathcal{O}(g)$ is a coboundary, not  $\mathcal{O}(f) $ itself.

Comment: well, you mean by composing $g$ with attaching maps of $k$-cells? Ok, what can I conclude from this?

Comment: you mean that I should conclude that $O(g)$ in this case coincides with $O(f)$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: maybe I'm confusing something. $f$ was assumed to be $ X^{(k-1)} \to Y$, otherwise we couldn't build $O(f)$. Now at which level you consider $g$ as an "extension" of $f$? In setting of Lemma 1.2 $g$ extends not $f$ itself but the restriction of $f$ to $k-2$ skeleton. Or do you apply the lemma 1.2 with all $k$'s leveled one up?

Comment: Sure. But the point is that the lemma is about $O(f)$ beeing a cocycle and a characterization when the difference $\mathcal{O}(f) - \mathcal{O}(g)$ is a coboundary. The lemma contains no statement about when $O(f)$ itself is a coboundary. On the other hand the obstruction condition is as you said about when $O(f)$ is a coboundary. Maybe your concern is that in the situation above $O(g)$ should vanish, but that's just a guess, I don't know. I have to admit that I can't follow you at that point.

Comment: If $f$ extends to $k$-skeleton then every $S^{k-1}  \xrightarrow{\eta_{e^k}}  X^{(k-1)} \xrightarrow{f}  Y$ factors through $D^k$ balls, and so $O(f)$ homotopically trivial? Is that what you mean? Alright than the class of $O(f)$ is coboundary

Comment: If that's what you mean, then the direction "$f$ extendable to $k$-level -> $O(f)$ coboundary"  not requires application of Lemma 1.2, so I gues it's the converse direction which exploits somehow lemma 1.2

Comment: Yes, and exactly there I see a problem with the right level $k$ to which 
the lemma / the "conversely..." part can be applied. So let now assume that $O(f)$ is coboundary 
- ie zero in $ H^k(X; \pi_{k-1}(Y,y_0))$ 
- and we want to show that we can lift $f$ to $X^k$. The problem is that since our $O(f)$ comes from $f : X^{(k-1)} \to Y$, the "converse" part of the lemma says only that we can find a $g: X^{(k-1)} \to Y$ agreeing with $f$ on $X^{(k-2)}$. But we want to lift $f$ to level $k$! Now as you said surely the lemma can be applied to all $k$. Yes, but if want a lift $g: X^k \to Y$

Comment: we need as input data $O(f)$ comming from $\overline{f}: X^k \to Y$, ie already a level higher. But the existence of such $\overline{f}$ is exactly what we want to prove. We haven't a priori this $\overline{f}$ as input data for the lemma

Comment: I think that your last statement in the update is not quite right.  There is an indexing problem. The statement that you wrote is just that the cocycle vanishes

Comment: @AndresMejia: You mean the statement that if $[O(f)]=0$ in $H^k(X; \pi_{k-1}(Y,y_0))$,
then $f : X^{(k-1)} \to Y$ extends to $X^{(k)}$ is not right? 
I am not sure if I can follow you. You mean there is an indexing problem 
*only* in what I wrote in the #Uptate part or also in the statement in Lemma 1.2 
respectively the remark on how $[O(f)]$ fulfils it's job as "obstuction class" 
in the linked text?

Comment: Also, I not understand what you mean by "The statement that you wrote is just that the cocycle vanishes". My goal is to understand the statement in the linked text that in view of the lemma 1.2, the cohomology class $[O(f)]$ is is the obstruction class. As far as I see this is equivalent to the statement that $[O(f)]$ vanishes as cohomology class (=is a boundary) iff $f$ extendable to $X^{(k)}$, do you agree? And then one direction is to assume that $[O(f)]$ is zero cohomology class, ie a boundary, and the goal is to show the extendability of $f$. Therefore I'm a bit confused

Comment: on what you mean by taht I wrote that "the cocycle vanishes". Why should it vanish? Maybe you mean that it's a boundary, so zero as cohomology class? If that's what you mean, then that's the assumption, isn't it? Or do I missing your point?

Comment: In lemma $1.2$, they are thinking of $\mathcal{O}(f)$ as an element of $C_n(X,\pi_{n-1}(Y))$, not the homology group (check the final sentence of your post)

Comment: @AndresMejia: I still not understand what you mean. When they write $O(f) $ they indeed consider it in lemma 1.2  as an element of $C^n(X,\pi_{n-1}(Y)) $ (so a cochain, by 1.2 even a cocycle), when they write it "in boxes" as $[O(f)] $ then they consider it as a class in $H^k(X; \pi_{k-1}(Y,y_0))$, see the "In view of the above lemma ... " part on page 2. Or do you just mean that in the last sentence of my #Update part I previously wrote something like  " $[ \mathcal{O}(f)] \in [ \mathcal{O}(f)] \in
H^k(X; \pi_{k-1}(Y,y_0)) $"? Well, that was indeed just a silly typo I corrected now.

Comment: But when I you mean really my last sentence "So my question reduces to the converse implication, namely why
Lemma 1.2 implies or verbatimly "in view of this lemma" we get the implication that if the class $ [ \mathcal{O}(f)] \in
H^k(X; \pi_{k-1}(Y,y_0))$ is zero, then 
$f : X^{(k-1)} \to Y$ extends to $X^{(k)}$." I not see what is else wrong there, except the mentioned typo. That should be a correct characterization of what a "obstruction class" should be, or not? sorry for the circumstances, maybe it's it's just sitting on my nose and i don't see it.

Comment: You also mentioned an "indexing problem". Where? Is there something wrong with some shift of $k$ in the lemma or in my text?

Comment: #a typo: where I wrote $C^n(X,\pi_{n-1}(Y))$ it should be $C^k(X,\pi_{k-1}(Y))$ to keep right indices with respect to lemma 1.2. I think that in your last comment you also meant $C^k(X,\pi_{k-1}(Y))$ and not $C_n(X,\pi_{n-1}(Y))$, what would be a chain, but $O(f)$ was constructed as cochain...

Answer (score 1):

Lemma 1.2 can be rephrased as
$$ \{g: [O(g)] = [O(f)] \} =\{g: g|X^{(k-2)} = f| X^{(k-2)} \} $$
It seems like 0 plays no role, so that we can't conclude the "extendable maps" are the one that lies in the class $[O(f)]=0$.

For example, consider the same lemma $O'(f):= O(f)+c$, where  is the fixed element of the involved cochain complex. The lemma would be the same, but the extendable maps would be the ones with $[O'(f)] = [c]$.

Maybe the textbook wanted to argue that the given obstruction parametrizes the extensions from $X^{(k-2)}$ to $X^{(k-1)}$, which *is* a consequence of the lemma. But it does not solve the extension problem from $X^{(k-1)}$ to $X^{(k)}$. Indeed, note that we should be really writing $O_k(f)$, and this is needed to check the extension to $X^{(k)}$, not to $X^{(k-1)}$.

I would rather say that $[O(f)]$ being an obstruction class plus lemma 1.2 show that extendability only depends on $f| X^{(k-2)}$, which is not a direct consequence of $[O(f)]$ being an obstruction class.